# Como limitar o tamanho do conteúdo pelo tamanho da div no flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Opa, eu dei uma pesquisada por aqui e não consegui achar algo que resolvesse.
Meu problema é, sempre que eu coloco um texto nos elementos que eu criei o tamanho respeita o conteúdo e não o contrário. Eu quero que o elemento limite o tamanho do conteúdo e se necessário criar um scroll. Usei o overflow mas ele não resolveu.

html

```
    <section id="container">
            <div class="item item1">DescriptiveOccaecat enim Lorem ut labore et deserunt labore eu quis minim consequat. Esse exercitation occaecat aliquip elit. Pariatur labore do ut non commodo cupidatat reprehenderit officia veniam. DescriptiveOccaecat enim Lorem ut labore et deserunt labore eu quis minim consequat. Esse exercitation occaecat aliquip elit. Pariatur labore do ut non commodo cupidatat reprehenderit officia veniam. DescriptiveOccaecat enim Lorem ut labore et deserunt labore eu quis minim consequat. Esse exercitation occaecat aliquip elit. Pariatur labore do ut non commodo cupidatat reprehenderit officia veniam.</div>
            <div class="item item2">2</div>
            <div class="item item3">3</div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 70Vh;
    width: 70vw; 
    margin: 0 15% 0 15%;
    box-shadow: 2px 10px 10px 10px #535050;
}

.item {
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal;

}

.item1 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.item2 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}

.item3 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu solucionei o problema dessa forma

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 70Vh;
    width: 70vw; 
    margin: 0 15% 0 15%;
    box-shadow: 2px 10px 10px 10px #535050;
}

.item {
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: auto; 
    height: auto;
}

.item1 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}

.item2 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50%;
}

.item3 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%;
```

Antes sem o width setado não estava funcionando o overflow (quando necessário), mas eu acredito que deve existir uma forma mais eficiente de fazer isso.
Eu só não coloquei a width no .item porque eu tenho mais elementos que vão utilizar widths diferentes mas que tem algumas propriedades semelhantes